# How to save the image in Parse.com with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, image-uploading

I am designing a web application and backend system is Express + Parse.Server. Currently , I get the problem with how to deal with save the picture in my Parse server.

Here is my ejs file

```
<html>

    <head>      
            <title>test</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action='/pictest' method='post'>
        <h3>test</h3>

        <input type="file" name="pic" id ="pict" >
        <input type='submit' value='Submit'>    
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

And this is the server.js

```
router.post('/pictest',function(req,res){
    var pic = req.body.pic;
    console.log(pic);
    if (pic.length > 0) {

      var file = new Parse.File("photo.jpg", pic, "image/png");

       file.save().then(function() {
       console.log("file save success");
       res.end();
       }, function(error) {
       console.log("file save error " + error.message);
        });

    }
    res.send('test');
});
```

This error I get is :

```
TypeError: Cannot create a Parse.File with that data.
   at new ParseFile (C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\example
\JavascriftLinkParse\node_modules\parse\lib\node\ParseFile.js:131:15)
   at C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\example\JavascriftLinkParse\routers\index.js:29:15
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\example
\JavascriftLinkParse\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at next (C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\example
\JavascriftLinkParse\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\example
\JavascriftLinkParse\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\example
\JavascriftLinkParse\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\example
\JavascriftLinkParse\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
   at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\example
\JavascriftLinkParse\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
   at next (C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\example
\JavascriftLinkParse\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
   at Function.handle (C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\example
\JavascriftLinkParse\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)
```

Any help would be helpfully appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you try with var pic = req.body.pic[0]; ?

Comment: I tried that but it's just show first the word of my picture name

Comment: Hey, have tou managed to solve this? I'm in the same situation..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) with express

and at the controller

```
var buffer = req.files.pic[0].buffer;
var base64 = buffer.toString('base64');
var name = "pic_name";
var file = new Parse.File(name, { base64: base64 });
```

Comment: Hi, Arturo
I tried to use your method and reference the multer express
And it had another error 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'pic' of undefined

Comment: did you install multer?